# Visual C# When are Close() and Dispose() Needed?

Tags: c#, file-io, dispose

I am new to Visual C# and don't understand when I need to use the Close() and Dispose() methods on FileStream and StreamReader objects. In the code snippet below, I open a file, read the first line, and validate that it is what is expected. Do I need all of the Close() and Dispose() calls shown? If not, when are they needed?
Thank you!

```
        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;

        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(txtMstrFile.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine = sr.ReadLine()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text) + " is an empty file.", "Empty Master File", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                if(!String.Equals(sLine, "Master File"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text) + " has an invalid format.", "Master File is Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
        // Code to process sLine here
                sr.Close();
            }
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text) + "\r\n" + ex.ToString(), "File Access Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
```

Comment: Generally you only need one of `Close` and `Dispose`, but it's good to read the documentation. Often, with a stream, you need to `Flush` it to complete any writes that are not yet fully written. Look up the `using` keyword. It provides an exception-tolerant mechanism for calling `Dispose` on `IDisposable` objects and simplifies your code

Answer (score 0):

*Explicit* `Dispose()` and `Close()` are rare avises in the typical code: `using` will do it for you:

```
   try {
     using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(txtMstrFile.Text, 
                                                     FileMode.Open, 
                                                     FileAccess.Read))) {
       string sLine = sr.ReadLine(); 

       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine)) {
         MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)} is an empty file.", 
                          "Empty Master File", 
                           MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                           MessageBoxIcon.Information);

         return;
       }
     
       if (!String.Equals(sLine, "Master File")) {
         MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)} has an invalid format.", 
                          "Empty Master File", 
                           MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                           MessageBoxIcon.Information);

         return;
       }  
     }  
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
     MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)}\r\n{ex}", 
                      "File Access Error", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error);

     return;
   }
```

Please, don't *concatenate* string when creating messages, *string interpolation*: `$" ... "` often is much more *readable*.

**Edit:** You can totally *get rid of* `Stream`s and `StreamReader`s:

```
   try {
     // That's enough to read the 1st file's line
     string sLine = File.ReadLines(txtMstrFile.Text).First();

     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine)) {
       MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)} is an empty file.", 
                        "Empty Master File", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);

       return;
     }
     
     if (!String.Equals(sLine, "Master File")) {
       MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)} has an invalid format.", 
                        "Empty Master File", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);

       return;
     }
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
     MessageBox.Show($"{Path.GetFileName(txtMstrFile.Text)}\r\n{ex}", 
                      "File Access Error", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error);

     return;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Some computer languages leave memory management to the programmer so freeing up memory that is no longer required is known as garbage collection. Dispose is the programmer's way of saying "clean up now". Close is for closing things like connections to databases. Close says "write any unwritten data to the file now" and is a safety measure that ensures that your file data is saved if your computer crash.

Comment: Actually, with streams, `Flush` is used to say _write any unwritten data to the streams store_